# How to read a property files into a map with @Bean and @AutoWire in WebAppConfig?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and I would like your help on how to read a property file in a WebAppConfig.java using a Map and with @Bean and @AutoWire. The constants in the property file is used as a common strings in different files (like an enum).

**myproperty.properties**

```
user.first_name = Jane
user.age = 23
```

**WebAppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( {"com.nokia.care.triggerengine", "com.nokia.care.gui.commons"} )
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource( "classpath:application.properties" )
public class WebAppConfig
extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
...
```

Furthermore the webappconfig.java already has an existing @propertsource.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With spring-boot you may create a separate config component and then autowire it.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
public class UserConfig {  
    private String userFirstName;
    private String userAge;
    //getters and setters
}

public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   private UserConfig userConfig;
   ...
}
```

Without spring-boot you should find needed dependencies for using `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: How about when I am using only a regular Spring Framework?
Is it possible to inject the property file into a map and then add it to a Bean then AutoWired it?

Answer (score 0):

Use  this @Value  to access value in bean and repository class

```
@Value("${user.first_name}")
private String userFirstName;

@Value("${user.age}")
private String userAge;
```

Comment: what if I have many constants in a property files and it is used as a common string in many different files. do i always have to declare it in every files?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is read all the configuration in an AppConfig class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration

@PropertySource("classpath:myproperty.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    private  Environment env;
    public  Environment getEnv(){
        return env;
    }

}
```

This way the env variable will have the map of all properties' key value pairs from myproperty.properties.
Now you can inject this AppConfig class in whichever class you like.
Like

```
public class A{
.
.
@Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;
.
.

private void method1(){
  int age= appConfig.getEnv().getProperty("user.age");
}
```

This way you can separate property-reading logic at one place, and make your code more modular.

Comment: Hi, thanks. What if the property file is put in a map and make the map as a  Bean and then AutoWired the map. Is this possible?